# Swift: Use of instance member on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'ViewController' instead

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

As the title suggests, Swift is telling me I'm calling a member on the ViewController class, not an object. I've looked at numerous other posts and cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
func endEventSteps() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "hasLoggedIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "usersEmail")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "usersPassword"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToLoginScreen", sender: self)
}
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "End event", message: "Are you sure you'd like to end this event?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "End",
                                          style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive,
                                          handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in endEventSteps()})
```

EDIT: I get the following error on the last line: "Use of instance member 'endEventSteps' on type 'InfoSubmisionViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'InfoSubmisionViewController' instead?". code compiles fine when I put simple command as the handler, such as print("foo")

All of the above code is within a custom ViewController class, 'InfoSubmissionViewController'.

Comment: What line is your error on? I do notice that `UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "usersPassword"` is missing the closing parentheses.

Comment: that's probably just a copy-paste issue. The error is on the last line, where I set endEventSteps() to be the handler. swift tells me:Use of instance member 'endEventSteps' on type 'InfoSubmisionViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'InfoSubmisionViewController' instead?

Comment: where are you calling the alertController?

Comment: @NateMann in an IBAction for a Button

Comment: The code is misleading because it pretends to be executed on the top level on the class which would cause a (different) compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a controller class named `DestructiveAction`, then

```
let DestructiveAction = ...
```

should be

```
let destructiveAction = ...
```